# Vertical scroll not being displayed when overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Hi I have a problem with a vertical scroll not being displayed in a container with `overflow:auto`. the problem is that the height of the container is exactly the same than the height of the content, but the content width is larger, so the horizontal scroll appears, that fact should force the vertical scroll to appear too, but it does not. any ideas?

Here a codepen because an example is better than the words.

https://codepen.io/xmorelll/pen/yLbObdJ

Comment: Thats because your content height is same as your container height. The scroll bar only appears when the content goes overflow. Try changing your content height to `600px` and see.

Comment: Hmmm.. then why not put y-scroll fixed? or change the height?

Comment: Yes. But when the horizontal scroll is there. The container height is 500px - 15px(of the scroll itself), so now the container real height is lower than the content which still is 500px.  The second box happen to have both scrolls even if the css is exactly the same.

Because the content height and width will depend on the user information. But the container is fixed. So I might have situations where the scrolls won't appear, others where only one scroll, but I don't see how to fix this case, where the content height is the same as the container but the width is larger.

Answer (score 0):

I try this code on chrome and firefox browsers. The problem is that different browsers might have different implementations for this. In chrome(Version 91.0.4472.114, Linux), the container is 485px but in firefox, it is with a width of 500px. The vertical scroll is also visible in my firefox browser(Version 89, Linux). When I change a CSS property of the container class in chrome, it is showing the vertical scroll. Basically, the (overflow: auto) will show scroll when the content exceeds either parent's width or height.

Comment: I am using 91.0.4472.114 on a Mac.  But I don't understant why at the start it does not show the vertical scroll in the left box. If it has the same html and styles than the right box.